# QNX7 and GCC 5.4.0 and CMAKE (fatal error: map: No such file or directory compilation terminated.)

Tags: c++11, gcc, cmake, qnx-neutrino

I use CMAKE to cross compile my code for QNX6.5 and using gcc/g++ 4.4.2

I added a new tool chain file for QNX7 using gcc/g++ 5.4.0.  My issue is that I am failing the build on standard includes like   , etc...
Errors like the following: fatal error: map: No such file or directory compilation terminated.

These headers are installed and at a similar location as QNX 6.5
Here's an example:

/opt/qnx650/target/qnx6/usr/include/c++/4.4.2/map

/opt/qnx650/target/qnx6/usr/include/c++/4.4.2/debug/map

/opt/qnx650/target/qnx6/usr/include/cpp/map

/opt/qnx700/target/qnx7/usr/include/c++/v1/map

/opt/qnx700/target/qnx7/usr/include/c++/5.4.0/profile/map

/opt/qnx700/target/qnx7/usr/include/c++/5.4.0/map

/opt/qnx700/target/qnx7/usr/include/c++/5.4.0/debug/map

Here is the relevant differences in the compile commands:
/opt/qnx650/host/linux/x86/usr/bin/qcc  -lang-c++ -DNDEBUG-lang-c++ -Vgcc_ntox86 -Wc,-Wall -O -Wc,*-std=gnu++0x* -O2 -funsigned-char -Werror -Wno-strict-aliasing -s -Wp,-isystem,/opt/qnx650/target/qnx6/usr/include

/opt/qnx700/host/linux/x86/usr/bin/q++  -lang-c++ -DNDEBUG -lang-c++ -Vgcc_ntox86 -Wc,-Wall -O -Wc,*-std=gnu++11 -stdlib=libstdc++ -Y _cxx* -O2 -funsigned-char -Werror -Wno-strict-aliasing -s -Wp,-isystem,/opt/qnx700/target/qnx7/usr/include

I tried adding -stdlib and -Y, but no matter the system doesn't seem to recurse through the include directories.

Any help is appreciated, I am guessing that there is some flag or compiler directive that is  required with the *newer* gcc compiler.  The CMAKE dependency files are the same for both and neither directly show a path to any files under the /usr/include/c++/xxx/

Comment: Try `g++ --verbose somefile.cxx` and see where it looks for header files.

Comment: Thanks - that helped a lot.  For qcc the compiler verbosity is -vv, this showed a typo in the other system include directories that are sourced using the QNX gcc_ntox86.conf file(s).